# Struggling With Some Simple Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am trying to write my javascript functions in a separate file functions.js. Right now that file consists of one function:

```
function noOverlay() {
    $('.overlay').css('display','none');
};
```

In my html I have these two lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/functions.js"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(
          noOverlay()
     );
</script>
```

Essentially what I am trying to do is house a function in an external file and call it in my html. Maybe $document.ready isn't the right way to do this. Or maybe I am just making a silly mistake. Thanks!

Comment: That method should be just fine. Are you 100% sure you're interpreting the symptoms correctly?  Although hackish, put in a console.log or alert in your function to see if it fires.

Comment: That method is not ok `noOverlay()` is being called immediately instead of on-ready. Ready expects a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are importing jQuery and try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/functions.js"></script>
<script>
     $(function () {
          noOverlay();
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  noOverlay();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure the js file was loaded with firebug or chrome's dev tools

Also make sure you load jQuery beforehand as well.